# equation of a plane with 3 points on axis

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

Well I'am stuck with one question about finding equation of a plane.. Few months ago I got at my exam question that sounded something like this:

*Find the equation of a plane if it cuts segment on x-axis,y-axis and z-axis in the ratio of 4:3:2 retrospective and if...* **rest of the text isn't important**

Sorry for bad explanation of the task, I had to translate it from my native language, if you don't understand something feel free to ask..

So finally, my question goes like this:

By this segments in question, am I allowed to take points with cordinates $(4,0,0), (0,3,0), (0,0,2)$

I know everything what I need to find equation of a plane,but I always get confused with segments like this, that's the thing on which I need help

Thanks

Comment: yes you are correct why don't you take general points (4k,0,0),(0,3k,0),(0,0,2k) and calculate the equation of the plane passing through this points

Comment: How do you know the rest of the text isn't important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to assume that those points lie on a desired plane satisfying the conditions of the problem. Notice that what the problem wants you to understand is that the given ratio $m:n:l$ is sort of like a generalization of the concept of slope in plane geometry when dealing with lines. Just like you can find a family of parallel lines with varying intercepts when you have been given the slope, you can find a family of parallel planes with the given ratio $m:n:l$, passing through different points in space.

To solve the problem, you can follow Deepesh Meena's solution. If you're looking for another way to solve the problem, you can first find two vectors created by the three points $(4,0,0)$, $(0,3,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$ and then calculate their cross product to find the normal vector of the plane spanned by them. Note that this plane will contain all the three points because it contains both vectors.

More precisely, in your problem, we can write

$$\vec{u}=(4,0,0)-(0,3,0) =(4,-3,0)$$
$$\vec{v}=(4,0,0)-(0,0,2) =(4,0,-2)$$

We know that $\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = (6,8,12)$ is orthogonal to both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. Hence, it is parallel to the normal vector of the plane containing $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. You can normalize $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ if you want, but it isn't necessary in this case.

So, the equation of **a** plane satisfying the given ratio can now be found as follows:

$$(6,8,12)\cdot\left((x,y,z)-(4,0,0)\right)=0$$

$$6(x-4)+8y+12z=0$$
$$6x + 8y + 12 z = 24$$
$$\frac{x}{4} + \frac{y}{3} + \frac{z}{2} = 1$$

Notice that the numbers in the denominator match your initial $4:3:2$ ratio.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation, could you answer me one more question if it's not problem. Sorry for asking a question into a question but I think approach to this is very similar..

Question: *Find equation of a plane which is parallel to $O_{x}$ axis, and on $O_{y}$ axis cuts slope(segment) of 1, and it goes through point $A(1,3,0).$*

Can I here also take point $B(0,1,0)$? Would this approach be correct:
$\alpha : || O_{x} \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{n}_{\alpha} + \overrightarrow{k}$
$\overrightarrow{n}_{\alpha} = \lambda(k \times AB)$
$AB = (-1,-2,0)$ 
This wont work

Comment: $k \times AB = \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k & \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \\ 
-1 & -2 & 0 & 
\\
\end{vmatrix} = 0i+0j+k$

$n_{\alpha} = (0,0,1)$

A = (1,3,0)

$0(x-1)+0(y-3)+1(z-0) = z$

I'am kinda sure this isn't the way, do I need to take put it in sequence mode then calculate it?

Comment: I made mistake here, it's parallel to $X$ axis, so we get $-2k$ and final solution is $-2z$

Comment: @PeroPeric   Notice that to use the cross-product method, you need to have two linearly independent vectors which is possible when you have three points which do no lie on the same line in the plane (whether you're choosing them on your own or they have been given to you by the problem).

Comment: @PeroPeric: By definition, the plane $P$ is parallel to the line $l$ if they do not intersect. One can argue that the plane we're looking for intersects the $x$-axis at an imaginary point at infinity. So, we're looking for a plane satisfying the ratios $\infty : m : n$ where $my+nz=c$ is the equation of a line in the $yz$-plan with slope $1$. This means that $m=-n$ and the desired ratios are $\infty : 1 : -1$ leading to $\frac{x}{\infty} + \frac{y}{1} + \frac{z}{-1} = k$. Plugging $(1,3,0)$ gives $k=3$. Hence, $y=z+3$ satisfies the requirements of your problem. Do you agree?

Comment: I guess you're right. I understand the idea, if you don't mind could you explain me this part when you get that $m = -n$

Comment: @PeroPeric   well, we want the slope of the line $my+nz=c$ to be equal to $1$. We know that the slope is given by $-\frac{n}{m}$. Hence $-\frac{n}{m}=1$ and $m=-n$.

Comment: thanks very much my friend, I understand it now :))

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct why don't you take general points $(4k,0,0),(0,3k,0),(0,0,2k)$ and calculate the equation of the plane passing through this points.

Suppose the equation of the plane is $ax+by+cz=d$

Now put these points in the plane you get

$$a(4k)=d$$
$$b(3k)=d$$
$$c(2k)=d$$

Pur back all the values in the first equation

Thus equation of your plane is $$\frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{3}+\frac{z}{2}=k$$